# Free Shipping for just one type of product

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

This might be an easy question, but it has me stumped. I have a rule set up that automatically gives the customer free shipping if they're ordering a certain type of product.

```
Fixed Amount Discount 
Discount Amount is 0  
Free Shipping "For matching items only"
```

Applied if the cart meets the following condition:

```
Category is 6
```

This works really well, but right now if the customer adds another product of a different category to the cart they're still getting the free shipping. How can I prevent this?

Edit: Is priority a factor here?

Comment: Have you solve your problem?

Comment: Does this work if used with starshipit shipping plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's may help to you.
In Condition

```
You can use assign rule for each sku
```

[image: Check this screenshot]
**In Action** select Free Shipping For matching items only.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately, as Magento still includes the free shipping even if other non-matching products exist. The clue here is where it says "If an item is found", otherwise it would read "if all items are found".

Answer (score 0):

There is a free module with a large variety of functions.

[Check this link](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/owebia/magento2-module-advanced-shipping-setting/blob/master/view/doc_en_US.html)

It may helps you, if you read the documentetion.